# Robot Framework - "No keyword with name 'Run Process' found" while Process library included

Tags: python, robotframework

I'm trying to understand how Robot Framework is working. So I did a little test using both those files:

• **hello.py**

```py
print('Hello')
```

• **TC_Hello.robot**

```
*** Settings ***
  Library  Process

*** Test Cases ***
Example of running a python script
  ${result}=  Run Process  python  D:\\RobotFrameworkTest\\Hello\\hello.py
  Should be equal as strings  ${result.stdout}  Hello
```

But I get the error `No keyword with name 'Run Process' found` for some reasons. So I checked SO and people seem to forget to include the library which is not my case.

Can anyone help me?

-- EDIT

I've tried running the robot file with another syntax which seem to run successfully for some reasons :

```
*** Settings ***
| Library | Process

*** Test Cases ***
| Example of running a python script
| | ${result}= | run process | python | D:\\RobotFrameworkTest\\Hello\\hello.py
| | Should be equal as strings | ${result.stdout} | Hello
```

BUT my employer don't like this syntax soooo...

Comment: Your code works for on my machine. I suppose Process library conflicts with another Python module with the same name, that does not have such function.

Comment: @BenceKaulics I did a `pip list` to see if there was a process module installed but there was none...

Comment: any other non-installed Python module that might be in the PYTHONPATH?

Comment: I have no environment variable called PYTHONPATH on my machine

Comment: Can you try `Process.Run Process` as an alternative?

Comment: @A.Kootstra I've tried it and the result was the same : `No keyword with the name 'Process.Run Process' found`. I also tried executing `python Process.Run\ Process` with no conclusive results either.

Comment: When I run both examples, using RED, Python 3.7.0, then both work just find. What command, or approach, do you use to run the Robot Framework test case? Is there any difference in the working and non-working approach?

Comment: The very only difference is the syntax. The environment is EXACLY the same.

Comment: Can you share your running approach and environment details?

Comment: Can you format your original code with Robot Tidy and retry?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

-- RESOLVED

So I noticed I put a tab right before the `Library Process` in the **settings** section. Therefore, `Process` was never included and the error was triggered.

This is working :

```
*** Settings ***
Library  Process # No tab at the beginning here

*** Test Cases ***
Example of running a python script
  ${result}=  Run Process  python  D:\\RobotFrameworkTest\\Hello\\hello.py
  Should be equal as strings  ${result.stdout}  Hello
```

I feel dumb rn. Thanks for your help anyway.

Comment: It was me who has edited out that tab from your question, I thought it was just some formatting or paste error. Sorry about that, I have learnt my lesson ^^. Thanks for posting this answer.

Comment: No problem haha ! @BenceKaulics It actually could have been it since I retyped the code from another computer. 

Comment: you saved my life thaaaaanks!!

Comment: I was making the same mistake... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> **Try the below sample code once, have "hello.py" in the test case path.
> If it is in test case path,you no need to give full path.
> It's working fine.**

Only change is file is place in testcase path.

**Version: Robot Framework 3.1.2 (Python 3.8.0 on win32)**

```
*** Settings ***
Library           Process

*** Test Cases ***
Example of running a python script
    [Tags]    Test
    ${result}=    Run Process     python     hello.py
    Log    all output: ${result.stdout} 
    Should be equal as strings  ${result.stdout}  Hello
```

[image]

Comment: Can you replicate the error by not having the path correct?

Comment: The OP's code works fine for others by default. You should reproduce the original error first to be sure you have really found the root cause.

Comment: What does both lines `[Tags]  Test` and `Log  all output: ${result.stdout}` do ?